# Unit Testing With iPhone MapKit Framework Freezes Test Build

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, mapkit

I have been performing unit tests on my iOS4.1 iPhone app successfully. I am currently trying to add some tests for a portion of my logic that uses APIs from the MapKit framework.

As soon as I add the MapKit framework to my LogicTest target, the target will not compile -- the compile process just hangs. This occurs even if I have no tests, startup or teardown logic. I think I might be missing some setting when adding the MapKit framework to a unit test build.

Interesting addition: if I change my base SDK to 3.2, the target will not hang during the compile (although, there will be errors because I am using API from 4.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept playing around with the frameworks associated with my unit test target. I added all of the frameworks, and it stopped hanging. Then I tried removing the frameworks one-by-one to see which one was needed along with the MapKit  -- guess what -- the problem went away. I can no longer re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I did add all the frameworks and it worked. Did you try doing a clean build after removing the unwanted frameworks?